# Insert array in multiple rows in postgres

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I have a variable which stores an array, 
eg `print_r ($template);`
Gives the following output

```
Array
(
   [0] => 351
   [1] => 352
)
```

I want to insert these values in a postgres table which has 2 columns (id,template).

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO "table"("id", "template") values ('."'$id'".','."'unnest($template)'".')';
$result = pg_query($sql);
```

Getting the following error

```
invalid input syntax for integer: &quot;unnest(Array)&quot;
```

Want the output to be like

```
----------
id | template
----------
12 | 351
----------
12 | 352
----------
```

Comment: id is primary key?if so then not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `id` is ***Not a primary key***.

Need to do like below:-

```
foreach($template as $temp){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `template`) values ($id,$temp)";
 $result = pg_query($sql);
}
```

Or do like below:-

```
$values = "";
foreach($template as $temp){
  $values .= "('".$id.",'".$temp."')";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `template`) values $values";
$result = pg_query($sql);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/817145

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple with [Pomm](http://www.pomm-project.org/news/a-short-focus-on-pomm-s-foundation.html):

```php
<?php //…
$sql = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO table (id, template)
  SELECT $*::int4 as id, unnest($*::int4[]) as template
RETURNING id, template
SQL;

$results = $pomm['my_session']
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query($sql, [12, [351, 352]]);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    printf(
        "id:%d => template:%d\n",
        $result['id'],
        $result['template']
        );
}
```

Comment: It's illustrative of frameworks that the "simple" example takes the most code and the most time to understand. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

pg_insert is more appropirate to execute this query, keys of the associative array are the column names of the table and values are data that you want to insert. You can have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-insert.php

````php
$data = Array
(
   [id] => 351
   [template] => 352
)

 $res = pg_insert($dbconn, 'post_log', $data);

  if ($res) {
      echo "data has been inserted\n";
  } else {
      echo "an error occurred\n";
  }```
````